# Sorting the list having multiple fields in one comparator

Tags: java, list, comparator

I was asked in an interview to sort the employee having `name`, `age`, `salary` using a single comparator in java. The precondition are:

1. There should be one comparator
2. There should not be any conditional block

Suppose if a user clicks on a name and ascending link in UI. The list should be sorted based on name ascending, if the user clicks on salary and descending link in UI, the list should be sorted on salary in descending order.

The single comparator should handle everything means based on the user input it should sort the list.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Ok, What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: is switch statement conditional?

Comment: IMHO, doing this with a single comparator would be bad design. Just use multiple comparators for the different sorts. A single comparator and then "no comparisons" is even worse, and will likely result in a very "clever" (i.e. hacky, overly complicated) solution.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Alternatively they are looking for a golfcode champion material or something - ill pass, my code is too verbose ;(

Comment: The difference between ascending and descending order is just a sign. Give the comparator a parameter to multiply the comparison-result with -1 for descending. - Or: use one comparator to sort ascending. In case of descending reverse the list after that.

Comment: Or use reflection to get field value by name, assume it is comparable and invoke `compare` on those

Comment: I have answered the below code,but it didint help                                      
 Class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
  public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
    int nameComp = emp1.getName().compareTo(emp2.getName());
  int ageComp = emp1.getAge().compareTo(emp2.getAge());
   int salaryComp = emp1.getSalary().compareTo(emp2.getSalary());
    if(nameComp == 0){
 return((ageComp ==0) ?ageComp: salaryComp);
 }else{
 return nameComp;
 }
  }
}

Comment: @sasmita   try with lambda expression Comparator java 8

Answer (score 0):

basically he is asking about:- how to use lambda expression with Comparator java 8.

Here is full Example:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class EmpCompare2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> companyTeam = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee empComparator1 = new Employee("Vipul", 25, 20000);
        Employee empComparator2 = new Employee("Amol", 21, 30000);
        Employee empComparator3 = new Employee("Sandeep", 22, 40000);
        Employee empComparator4 = new Employee("Sagar", 23, 60000);
        Employee empComparator5 = new Employee("kamal", 24, 6000);
        Employee empComparator6 = new Employee("Zandu", 20, 5000);
        companyTeam.add(empComparator1);
        companyTeam.add(empComparator2);
        companyTeam.add(empComparator3);
        companyTeam.add(empComparator4);
        companyTeam.add(empComparator5);
        companyTeam.add(empComparator6);

        // sort by age
        Collections.sort(companyTeam, new Comparator<Employee>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
                return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
            }
        });

        // lambda
        companyTeam.sort((Employee o1, Employee o2) -> o1.getAge() - (o2.getAge()));

        // lambda
        companyTeam.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getAge() - (o2.getAge()));
        System.out.println("After Sorting BY Age: companyTeam " + companyTeam);

        // sort by salary
        Collections.sort(companyTeam, new Comparator<Employee>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });

        // lambda
        companyTeam.sort((Employee o1, Employee o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));

        // lambda
        companyTeam.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
        System.out.println("After Sorting : companyTeam " + companyTeam);
    }

}
```

Or you can use bellow code for bellow java 8 environments.

we can have 3 boolean ageFlag = false;, boolean nameFlag = true;,   boolean salaryFlag = false;, as like bellow flag value can we from UL click

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class EmpDataCompare implements Comparator<Employee> {

    boolean ageFlag = false;
    boolean nameFlag = true;
    boolean salaryFlag = false;



    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        if (ageFlag) {
            return (emp1.getAge() - emp2.getAge());
        }
        if (nameFlag) {
            int nameComp = emp1.getName().compareTo(emp2.getName());
            return ((nameComp == 0) ? emp1.getName().compareTo(emp2.getName()) : nameComp);
        }
        if (salaryFlag) {
            return (emp1.getSalary() - emp2.getSalary());
        }

        return (emp1.getAge() - emp2.getAge());// return by default compare value by age

    }

}
```

but I would like to recommend we should have seprate Comparator Class implementation to use the name, age, salary attribute of Employee to sort the employee as per rule of separation of concerns in java [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns] or use Java 8 style code